# get last record per category filter by date

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this tables [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8192e1/11)

items table:

```
+----+----------+
| id |   name   |
+----+----------+
|  1 | Facebook |
|  2 | Twitter  |
|  3 | Amazon   |
+----+----------+
```

prices table:

```
+----+-----------+---------+-----------------------------+
| id |    buy    | item_id |             created_at      |
+----+-----------+---------+-----------------------------+
|  1 |   43000   |    1    | June, 18 2014 17:31:04+0000 |
|  2 |   44000   |    1    | June, 19 2014 17:31:04+0000 |
|  3 |   30000   |    2    | June, 20 2014 17:31:04+0000 |
|  4 |   33000   |    2    | June, 21 2014 17:31:04+0000 |
|  5 |   20000   |    3    | June, 22 2014 17:31:04+0000 |
|  6 |   21000   |    3    | June, 23 2014 17:31:04+0000 |
+----+-----------+---------+-----------------------------+
```

I want to get last prices per item and one before last price's buy field based on a price date

Desired output:

```
+----+---------+-----------------+---------+
| id |   buy   | last_before_buy | item_id |
+----+---------+-----------------+---------+
| 10 |  45000  |     43000       |    3    |
| 7  |  33000  |     31000       |    2    |
| 4  |  23000  |     23000       |    1    |
+----+---------+-----------------+---------+
```

Comment: You should be pulling your starting data in here, just to prevent link rot.  What have you tried?  This sounds like it starts as a [tag:greatest-n-per-group] problem, do none of the standard answers work?

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse i added data, my problem solved by Fabricator, tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's another way to do it:

```
select a.id, a.buy, b.buy last_before_buy, a.item_id
from (select * from prices WHERE (created_at <= NOW() - INTERVAL 5 DAY) order by id desc) a
join (select * from prices order by id desc) b on a.item_id = b.item_id and a.id > b.id
group by a.item_id;
```

[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8192e1/40)

Comment: tnx with this i get the last result how could i get for example last item with their price from 1 week ago?

Comment: does using `order by id desc` in the derived table guarantee that the most recent `a.buy` will be selected?

Comment: @Xengil, to get arbitrary time ago, you change `a.id > b.id` to `b.trade_time < DATE_SUB(CURDATE(), INTERVAL 1 WEEK)`

Comment: @Fabricator yes, i changed your code to [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8192e1/40) i get proper result, this is my prefered result, tnx again

Comment: @Fabricator because of my title (filter based on date) please change your answer to be like [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/8192e1/40)

Comment: @Xengil, there you go

Comment: @Xengil, you might want a `left join` since sometimes no record found from earlier time

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with the `substring_index()`/`group_concat()` trick:

```
select max(id) as id,
       substring_index(group_concat(buy order by created_at desc), ',', 1) as buy,
       substring_index(substring_index(group_concat(buy  order by created_at desc), ',', 2), ',', -1) as lastbuy,
       item_id
from prices p
group by item_id;
```

Comment: add this to fit his desire `order by id desc`